# How can I implement loops and if-else logic for ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to build a simple quiz game using Swing.  The user should be able to pick a fruit or vegetable from the combobox and guess if it is a fruit or vegetable.  If they guess correctly, the GUI should output "yes". If they guess wrong, it should output "no".  The code seems to compile correctly, but it is not running correctly.

I am using an if-else loop within the "fruit" and "vegetable" button's ActionListener in order to determine if the user guessed correctly.

```
public class GUI {

    public static String input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI()
    {


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Simple GUI");
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        final String[] fruitOptions = {"Apple", "Apricot", "Banana"
                ,"Cherry", "Date", "Kiwi", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry"};



        final String[] vegOptions = {"Asparagus", "Beans", "Broccoli", "Cabbage"
                , "Carrot", "Celery", "Cucumber", "Leek", "Mushroom"
                , "Pepper", "Radish", "Shallot", "Spinach", "Swede"
                , "Turnip"};

        String[] combined = {"Apple", "Apricot", "Banana"
                ,"Cherry", "Date","Cucumber", "Leek", "Mushroom"
                , "Pepper", "Radish","Kiwi", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Asparagus", "Beans", "Broccoli", "Cabbage"
                , "Carrot", "Celery","Shallot", "Spinach", "Swede"
                , "Turnip"};




        JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel comboLabel = new JLabel("Is it a Fruit or Vegetable?:");
        final JComboBox fruitsVeggies = new JComboBox(combined);

        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                input = (String) fruitsVeggies.getSelectedItem();

            }
        };



        fruitsVeggies.addActionListener(actionListener);
        comboPanel.add(comboLabel);
        comboPanel.add(fruitsVeggies);


        final JButton fruitButton = new JButton( "Fruit");
        JButton vegButton = new JButton("Vegetable");



        final JLabel yes = new JLabel("YES");
        final JLabel no = new JLabel("NO");


        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() 
        {



            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent d)
            {
                int i;

                for(i=0; i<vegOptions.length-1; i++) 
                {
                    if (input.equals(fruitOptions[i])) 
                    {
                         yes.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else
                        no.setVisible(true);
                }   




            }
        };


        ActionListener vegListener = new ActionListener() 
        { 


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f)
            {
                int i;

                for(i=0; i<vegOptions.length-1; i++) 
                {
                    if (input.equals(fruitOptions[i])) 
                    {

                         no.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else

                        yes.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        };

        no.setVisible(false);
        yes.setVisible(false);
        fruitButton.addActionListener(listener);
        vegButton.addActionListener(vegListener);

        frame.add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.add(vegButton,BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(fruitButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(yes, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(no, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what's the problem, specifically? All you have said is that "it is not running correctly". Is the output different from what you expect? For which input(s) is this the case?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Use one JLabel, and the `setText()` method to change the output.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is with the following code

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent d)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<vegOptions.length-1; i++) 
    {
        if (input.equals(fruitOptions[i])) 
        {
            yes.setVisible(true);
        }
        else
        {
            no.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

With each iteration of your loop you're setting the visibility of one of your labels. Instead you should check the result in the loop and then set the visibility after. Also, you appear to checking only if the input is a fruit, and if so, setting yes to visible. This isn't a correct comparison. You should be checking if the type of the selection matches the users guess.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declaring component variable local to method is not preferable especially when you will need to use means of Anonymous class which will need your component variable declared to be `final`. Declare the component variable in the class context.
2. No need to use two separate `JLabel` to show `YES` and `NO` for correct input. Use one `JLabel` and make use of `setText(string)` method of `JLabel`. When a decision is yet to take, use `resultNo answer is chosen` or similar which make sense to you. For example:

   ```
   answerLabel = new JLabel("No answer is chosen"); 
               // answerLabel is a JLabel declared in class context
   ```
3. You have mistakes in your `actionPerformed` function as pointed out below:

   ```
       public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent d)
      {
         int i;

       for(i=0; i<vegOptions.length-1; i++) 
       {
           if (input.equals(fruitOptions[i]))  //<---i  is bounded to vegOptions length
                        //but iterating over fruitOptions !!
                answerLabel.setText("YES! Correct Answer");

           else
               answerLabel.setText("NO! Wrong Answer");
       }   

   }
   ```

And similar changes to other action component, i.e., two `JButton`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<vegOptions.length-1; i++) 
{
    if (input.equals(fruitOptions[i]))
        yes.setVisible(true);
    else
        no.setVisible(true);
}
```

This code is wrong.

The first problem, as mentioned by Sage, is that `vegOptions.length-1` should be `fruitOptions.length` - you are checking the fruits, not the vegetables.

The other problem might not be obvious at first. Let's say the user enters "apple". The code checks "apple" (their input) against "apple" (from fruitOptions), and displays the "yes" label. Then the code checks "apple" (their input) against "apricot" (from fruitOptions) and displays the "no" label. After the loop, both the "yes" and "no" labels will be visible.

This code should work. Make sure you understand why it works:

```
boolean isInArray = false;
for(i=0; i<fruitOptions.length; i++) 
{
    if (input.equals(fruitOptions[i]))
    {
        isInArray = true;
    }
}

if(isInArray)
{
    yes.setVisible(true);
    no.setVisible(false);
}
else
{
    no.setVisible(true);
    yes.setVisible(false);
}
```

Note that neither problem has anything to do with ActionListener.

Also as Sage pointed out, there's no need to have two JLabels when you can have one and change the text on it.